# Calculate subtraction between pulses after fix amount of time

Tags: javascript, java, algorithm, data-structures

My purpose is to sync between pulses that continuously arrive from 2 sides : SUPPLY, RETURN side.

The same piece of code handle the logic for both sides , each pulse has count. I'd like to write a code that make diff every 1 min that ensure both pulses arrived. My code now handle only validation after 1 sec using compression between the timestamps as in example below (written in java but any javascript/ pseudocode ok)

```
public class Detector {

    long supplyEpochSecond = -1;
    long returnEpochSecond = -1;
    int supplyCount;
    int returnCount;

    void calcDiffs (SensorPulse pulse, Source source){

        LocalDateTime pulseTime = pulse.getLocalDateTime();
        long epochSecond = pulseTime.toEpochSecond(ZoneOffset.UTC);
        boolean oneSecondPassed = oneSecondPassed(epochSecond, source == Source.SUPPLY);
        if (oneSecondPassed) {
            /**
             * TODO add logic instead of make after one second
             * need sync after 1 min and calculate diff between supply and return counts
             */
            int diff = supplyCount - returnCount;
            System.out.println("Count diff after 1 sec:" + diff); // need after 1 min pass

           supplyCount = 0;
           returnCount = 0;
        }
        int count = pulse.getCount();
        if (source == Source.SUPPLY) {
            supplyEpochSecond = epochSecond;
            supplyCount += count;
        } else {
            returnEpochSecond = epochSecond;
            returnCount += count;
        }
    }

    private boolean oneSecondPassed(long epochSecond, boolean isSupply) {
        if (supplyEpochSecond == -1 || returnEpochSecond == -1) { // not started yet
            return false;
        }
        if (supplyEpochSecond == returnEpochSecond) { // got measures from both last time
            return epochSecond > supplyEpochSecond;
        }
        return (supplyEpochSecond > returnEpochSecond) == isSupply; // one measure is missing
    }
```

Any ideas how subtract between pulses count after 1 min pass ? (not 1 sec as now)
using modulo % 60 ?

Comment: Since you already detect when 1 second has passed, you could add a separate int variable to track how many times this has been hit. When its hit 60 times then its 1 minute

Comment: we need get rid of 1 sec method as it was approximately example

Comment: you can try running a thread which awakes after one min and do the action as one method. Another method just to manage the count values which will be used by thread at the 1 min time. So it is more like parallel threads which are sharing info with each other, one is getting count and another one is taking action based on that (sub in this case)

Comment: Thanks, might be, if it possible can you share the solution code ?